# Selector matrix only shows 6 workspaces on panel

Tags: gnome-panel, workspace-switcher

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with the workspace matrix switcher.

It will show 6 workspaces on the bottom-panel of my screen, but if I add more workspaces then it won't show any, it just shows a count of the number of workspaces. If I click on it, it will show a pop-up list, but I don't want that.

Previously I had Ubuntu 18.04 and could show 14 workspaces. How can I increase the limit on 22.04?

Does it have to do with the arrangement of the panel? It's only  about half-filled already. I've gone through the dash-to-panel menu but don't see any control that would affect this.

Comment: I also posted the issue here:
https://github.com/mzur/gnome-shell-wsmatrix/issues/232

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix:

```
sudo vi /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js        # Set MAX_THUMBNAILS=20. Was =6.
gnome-extensions disable workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
gnome-extensions enable  workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

Note that the edit would have to be repeated if the extension is updated.